# How to dismiss alertController for ipad in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, uialertcontroller

I am loading a website with WkWebview and the website contains some javascript actions. For iPhone, it is working fine because the confirmPanel would not allow user to touch outside the panel until user choose the available actions in the panel. However, for iPad it does not do the same things as iPhone. Whenever 
i try to touch outside of the alert panel, it will crash. Please see the crash logs below the code. I tried using UITapGestureRecognizer, but it is still not working.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(true)
    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(false)
    }))

    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom != .phone {
        if let popoverController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
            popoverController.sourceView = self.view
            popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
            popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []
        }
    }

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Error message,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Completion handler passed to -[webViewios.MainVC webView:runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:completionHandler:] was not called'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x21a2f91b 0x211cae17 0x21a2f861 0x287d7293 0x288111b9 0x2886db69 0x21603ac3 0xccd4c 0x8d9e1f 0xcc6d8 0x8d9e1f 0xd1718 0x21603ac3 0x26400cd1 0x263ff26b 0x211e53a9 0x2193ef89 0x219f006f 0x2193f229 0x2193f015 0x22f2fac9 0x26013189 0xd8824 0x215e7873)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the iPad, when you present the action sheet cancel action is automatically mapped to the tap outside the control panel of the action sheet.  You need to make a change in the way you are showing  `Cancel` button of your `UIAlertController`.

**Updated Code without Cancel button on iPad**

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(true)
    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(false)
    }))

    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom != .phone {
        if let popoverController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
            popoverController.sourceView = self.view
            popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
            popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []
        }
    }

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Code with Cancel button on iPad**

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(true)
    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(false)
    }))

    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom != .phone {
         alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) in
             completionHandler(false)
        }))
        if let popoverController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
            popoverController.sourceView = self.view
            popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
            popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []
        }
    }

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Finally! so far it doesn't crash when i touch outside. However, how am i going to add a cancel button?

Comment: In iPad, when you present the `UIAlertController` with `UIPopoverPresentationController`. The cancel button action is mapped to the context touch outside the panel, its default behavior of the actionSheet in the iOS. If you still need the cancel button then add an additional `Cancel` button for iPad of type `default`.

Comment: Hi, i just found out that, i have this error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20c) at completionHandler(false)'s cancel button for ipad. i think it is because the alertController is being presented and i click another button to present again. Sometimes will have this error Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x149bac00>  on <iosWebView.MainVC: 0x14581720> which is already presenting (null).

Comment: you can check `self.presentingViewController == nil` before presenting `UIAlertController`, can you please explain detail in which scenario you are getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Comment: I only have iPad 2 and version is iOS 9.3.5. Whenever i clicked on the javascript button, then it will present the alert controller. So i tried to click many times on the button. It showed the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`... When i tried to use it on simulator with the version of iOS 10 and 11, so far no problem with it.

Comment: put the check if `self.presentingViewController != nil { return }` before presenting new alert to avoid crash.

Answer (score 0):

Present your `UIAlertController` if `UIViewController` with `WKWebView` is visible. If not visible, execute `completionHandler` directly and return.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
    completionHandler(true)
}))

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
    completionHandler(false)
}))

if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom != .phone {
    if let popoverController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverController.sourceView = self.view
        popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
        popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []
    }
}

    if self.viewIfLoaded?.window != nil {
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

Comment: May i know how to configure the isVisible() ? and the completionHandler() is missing argument. it needs a BOOL and it doesnt allow empty.

Comment: it is still crashing when i touch outside of the alert panel. Also, the completionHandler() needs an argument. I tried for True and false, and it is not working too.